# Need help.. Can someone tell me why the query is not executing?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$selectResitDate = "SELECT startdate FROM resit";
$runselectResitDate = mysqli_query($conn, $selectResitDate);
if (!$runselectResitDate) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runselectResitDate)) 
{
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($row=['startdate']);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $diff=$interval->format('%a');
    echo $diff;
}
```

plz help, it just doesnt work.. show no result
ive seen this problem many times, can someone tell me why this problem is happening and how to avoid this?

Comment: run `SELECT startdate FROM resit` to phpmyadmin and see may be you table or column name is miss-spelled.

Answer (score 4):

Remove that equals sign:

```
$datetime2 = new DateTime($row=['startdate']);
                              ^
```

it should be:

```
$datetime2 = new DateTime($row['startdate']);
```

Otherwise you just assign a `$row` a single element array and use it as an argument for `Datetime` function instead of fetching the value.

Also, change `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error($conn)`.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad you did it. If you are OK with my answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is causing the problem.when we access the array value by it's key we use like `$array['key']`. So use 
:

`$datetime2 = new DateTime($row['startdate']);`

instead of:

`$datetime2 = new DateTime($row=['startdate']);`

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
$datetime2 = new DateTime($row=['startdate']);
```

To :

```
$datetime2 = new DateTime($row['startdate']);
```

Or you can also try this code

```
$conn = mysql_connect("host", "user", "password");

    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if (!mysql_select_db("yourdbname")) {
        echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT startdate FROM resit";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $datetime2 = new DateTime($row['startdate']);
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        $diff=$interval->format('%a');
        echo $diff;
    }
```

Comment: Please do not use or suggest `mysql` to any one use `PDO` or `mysqli`.